# Excel vba If And Then inputting numerical values and outputting non numerical

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, conditional-statements, vba

I am new at this and need some help - I am sorry if my question is a little unclear.

I want to create an If-Then statement using a range of numbers (with one decimal place) as my Range, and for the output to be in non numerical form (a word or code)

This is what I have, when I first tried it, it worked. I saved it but it now stopped working and after clicking on the command button, nothing happens.

```
Dim score As Double, result As String

If Range("E2") >= 18.6 And Range("E2") <= 21.5 Then
  Range("F2") = "2a"

Else
  If Range("E2") >= 21.6 And Range("E2") <= 24.5 Then
    Range("F2") = "3c"

  End If
End If
```

So if I enter a number between 18.6 and 21.5 in cell E2, I would like the code "2a" to appear in cell F2.

Comment: Are you sure you are on the correct sheet? When you don't specify what sheet your ranges are on, it is easy to run into trouble. I can't see any other obvious problems with your code at any rate.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved it. I had by mistake added a letter in the name of the sheet. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Your syntax is correct (as the comments indicate). A couple tips (if you are interested). Because a cell can also be a string, and because a string will compare as greater then a number, you can get weird results. One way to know for sure what you are dealing with would be just to test it. Also, you might find the "Select Case" Syntax helpful:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim score As Double, result As String
    If IsNumeric(Range("E2").Value) Then
        Select Case Range("E2").Value
            Case 18.6 To 21.5
                Range("F2") = "2a"
            Case 21.6 To 24.5
                Range("F2") = "3c"
            Case Else
                'Do something else if you want to:)
        End Select
    Else
        'Do something else if you want to:)
    End If
End Sub
```